# Ansible: restart Apache only once, not multiple times when using service - method with with_items list

Tags: apache, ansible

I have a basic deployment playbook, that copies over couple of Apache configuration files and python files with Ansible, and for some of the files the state is registered so I can reload Apache if the files are changed.

I can't figure out how to set up reloading Apache so if 4 of the files are changed, Apache would reload only once ( currently it is being reloaded once per changed file).

Playbook I'm using:

```
- name: Copy apache files
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  copy: src=../files/index.html dest=/var/www/docs/index.html owner=root  group=root mode=755

- name: Copy app variable file
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  copy: src=../files/app_vars dest=/etc/app owner=root group=root mode=644       

- name: Copy pyapp files
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  copy: src=../files/pyapp.py dest=/var/www/pyapp/pyapp.py owner=flask group=flask mode=755
  register: pyapp

- name: Copy wsgi files
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  copy: src=../files/pyapp.wsgi dest=/var/www/pyapp/pyapp.wsgi owner=flask group=flask mode=755
  register: wsgi

- name: Copy apache files
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  copy: src=../files/pyapp.conf dest=/etc/httpd/conf.d/pyapp.conf owner=root group=root mode=644
  register: pyapp_conf

- name: Copy apache files
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  copy: src=../files/docs.conf dest=/etc/httpd/conf.d/docs.conf owner=root group=root mode=644
  register: docs

- name: Reload Apache configs if pyapp or Apache - files are changed
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  service: name=httpd state=reloaded
  when: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - pyapp.changed
    - wsgi.changed
    - pyapp_conf.changed
    - docs.changed
```

Comment: [Handlers: Running Operations On Change](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change)

Answer (score 1):

You could change playbook with:

```
tasks:
    - name: copy files
      copy: src={{ item.src }} dest={{ item.dest }} owner={{ item.owner }} group={{ item.group }} mode={{ item.mode }}
      with_items:
      - {src: '../files/pyapp.wsgi', dest: '/var/www/pyapp/pyapp.wsgi', mode: 755, owner: 'flask', group: 'flask'}
      - ... <all other files you copy>
      notify: httpd restart

handlers:
    - name: httpd restart
      service: name=httpd state=reloaded
```

Move `become:yes` up to start of playbook right after `hosts:`.

Comment: I tend to do this type of thing mode: "{{item.m | default(0644) }}", then you can bit a bit lazier in the list